# iScroll 4 performance on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, gwt, iscroll4, iscroll

I was impressed by the smoothness of the [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) on iOS so i tried to implement it in my iPhone application.

The [iScroll Demo](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/pull-to-refresh/) works real fine on my iPhone. But only when the scrollable content is as simple as short text in `<li>` elements:

```
<ul id="thelist">
    <li>Pretty row 1</li>
    <li>Pretty row 2</li>
    <li>Pretty row 3</li>
        etc..
</ul>
```

When i tried to put a slightly more complex contents :

```
<ul>
    <li class="GOE-WOTBDO GOE-WOTBIO GOE-WOTBEO " __idx="0">
        <div class="cssDivStyle">
                <img width="120px" height="74px" src="http://some_jpg_image.jpg">
        </div> 
        <div> 
            <p>Some long text ....</p>
        </div>
    </li>
```

The smoothness is completely gone, and the list hardly scrolls ..

Is there a way to make my contents lighter ?

Any suggestions whatsoever ? Thank you very much !

Here's how i declare my iScroll element:

```
myScroll = new $wnd.iScroll(
            elem,
            {
                useTransition : true,
                topOffset : pullDownOffset,
                hScroll : false,
                onRefresh : function() {
                    if (pullDownEl.className.match('loading')) {
                        pullDownEl.className = 'pullDown';
                        pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull down to refresh...';
                    }
                },
                onScrollMove : function() {
                    if (this.y > 5 && !pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                        pullDownEl.className = 'flip pullDown';
                        pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Release to refresh...';
                        this.minScrollY = 0;
                    }

                },
                onScrollEnd : function(response) {
                    if (pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                        pullDownEl.className = 'loading pullDown';
                        pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
                        app.@ma.xxx.xxxxx.clientcommon.utils.IPhoneScroller::callbackSuccess(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/AsyncCallback;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)(pullDownCallback,response);
                    }
                }
            });
```

[EDIT]

only by removing `divs` from:

```
<ul>
    <li class="GOE-WOTBDO GOE-WOTBIO GOE-WOTBEO " __idx="0">
        <div class="cssDivStyle">
            <img width="120px" height="74px" src="http://some_jpg_image.jpg">
        </div> 
        <div> 
            <p>Some long text ....</p>
        </div>
</li>
```

and making it to:

```
<ul>
    <li class="GOE-WOTBDO GOE-WOTBIO GOE-WOTBEO " __idx="0">
        <img class="cssDivStyle" width="120px" height="74px" src="http://some_jpg_image.jpg">
        <p>Some long text ....</p>
    </li>
```

Made the scrolling much, much faster !! I have no idea why!

Comment: From experience, I would avoid iscroll for anything too rich. Its an awesome script, but I have tried myself to get it to work butter smooth to no avail. Instead I would recommend using position fixed containers if you are using I scroll to keep your footer and headers still. That works wonders and will gracefully degrade on older devices

Comment: @AndresGallo thank you for the comment. But i don't understand how to use the position fixed container ? My footer and header are indeed position fixed, only the main body is scrollable..

Comment: so you are already using css position fixed, and only your main body is scrollable right? 
I am probably misunderstanding something...if thats the case why are you using iscroll? Using css you don't really need iScroll to get the header and footer to stay in place. (this is true in ios 5 and android devices as old as 2.1)

Comment: So i have a fixed header in the top, and a fixed footer in the bottom and in between there's a `<UL>` list as described in my question. I scroll the list vertically using iScroll while keeping my header and footer still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will render your page the way webkit expects it. So redrawing will be massively quicker.

The HTML

```html
<body>
    <div class="headerFix">
        <div class="header">
            <!-- The content in header...logo/menu/e.t.c -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"><!-- you dont need this extra div but it keeps structure neat -->
        <ul>
            <li>List content here which can be as complex as needed</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footerFix">
        <div class="footer">
            <!-- The content in footer -->
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

The css

```css
.headerFix, .header {
    height:50px; /*important to share width in both divs*/    
    width:100%;
    background:red;
}

.headerFix, .footerFix {
    position:relative;
}

.header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    /*this is now fixed, but the parent being in flow keeps this div from overlapping your list which is why the height had to be the same for both*/
}

ul li {
    /*basic list look for sample purposes*/
    display:block;
    min-height:40px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #777;
}

.footerFix, .footer {
    height:50px; /*important to share width in both divs*/
    width:100%;
    background:red;
}


.footer {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    /*you will need to use javascript to find the height of device screen to know what the css value for "top" should really be. This will take some work on android where getting screen sizes is funky if you plan to support it. */
    /*If its iphone only you can assume the size which has always been the same, and make an exception for the new iphone 6. I say use javascript to position this footer if you plan to support many platforms*/
}
```

By the way I recommend using this meta tag in your html head to make sure you use the screen at its best

```html
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I have a slightly similar layout, but i haven't used js to fix the top of the footer though. Meanwhile I made my `<li>` contents slightly lighter by removing the two divs inside and leaving only `img` and `p` tags and now it works just fine..!! I upvoted your answer and if i have yet more complex data inside my li i'll try your solution

Answer (score 0):

When I use 'iscroll-lite.js' library in my mobile application, I fall same problem. Then I had little change in 'iscroll-lite.js' library.

Simply add e.preventDefault() to '_move:' function in 'iscroll-lite.js';

It resolve my problem.